# Powershell script with Get-Mailbox and Get-MailboxStatistics missing output

Tags: powershell

I'm using a powershell script to determine the size of the mailboxes of users in my office 365 tenant.
This works almost fine but only for the first returned item the e-mailaddress of the user is not shown.
In this cae it should be: username1@contoso.com
But it stays blank

Why?

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Where {$_.EmailAddresses -like 
"*@contoso.com"} | Get-MailboxStatistics |
Select-Object -Property @{label=”User”;expression={$_.DisplayName}},
@{label="Emailaddress";e={(get-mailbox $_.legacyDN).PrimarySMTPAddress}},
@{label=”Total Messages”;expression= {$_.ItemCount}},
@{label=”Total Size (MB)”;expression={[math]::Round(`
($_.TotalItemSize.ToString().Split("(")[1].Split(" ")[0].Replace(",","")/1MB),2)}}
```

The result is the following output.
Missing the e-mailaddress on the first line.

```
User        Emailaddress             Total Messages Total Size (MB)
----        ------------             -------------- ---------------
Username 1                                    15977         2844,87
Username 2  username2@contoso.com               546            3,41
```

Comment: Ooops, I just noticed now that the actual question was "Why?". Sorry, I don't have an answer to that. At first I thought you were looking for a solution. ;-)

Comment: May I ask why you use `(get-mailbox $_.legacyDN).PrimarySMTPAddress` instead of `get-mailbox $_.PrimarySMTPAddress` on line 4. I tried to use your code and this part really confusing me. My suggestion works fine though.
`Get-mailbox %mailbox_name% | fl *` does not have `legacyDN` attribute

Comment: @TeslaGreat I can answer that. In this code you have to deal with the properties of `Get-MailboxStatistics` for the calculated properties. But that does not have a property "PrimarySMTPAddress".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `Foreach-Object` loop and a custom object to achive what you need like this:

```
 Get-Mailbox -Filter "EmailAddresses -like '*@contoso.com'" -ResultSize Unlimited | 
    ForEach-Object{
        $Statistics = Get-MailboxStatistics -Identity $_.sAMAccountName
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            User = $_.DisplayName
            Emailaddress = $_.PrimarySMTPAddress
            'Total Messages' = $Statistics.ItemCount
            'Total Size (MB)' = [math]::Round(($Statistics.TotalItemSize.ToString().Split("(")[1].Split(" ")[0].Replace(",","")/1MB),2)
        }
    }
```

It could be even a little bit faster because you don't need to run your `Get-Mailbox` cmdlet twice.

Answer (score -1):

To stop receiving warning or error, please use these steps

```
$WarningAction ='Ignore'
$WarningAction = 'SilentlyContinue'
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?