# Powershell Custom column returning empty value with certain cmdlets

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, powershell-2.0, exchange-server-2010

When adding a custom column with the get-mailbox cmdlet i get an empty value.

I'm trying to add a custom column using select @{} on the get-mailbox cmdlet. no matter what i tried the result is always an empty value, i changed the original cmdlet and replaced it with say get-process and then it did work.
I even tried with explicitly providing a username and not relying on the pipeline variable, and it didn't work.

```
get-mailbox <username> | select name, @{name="size"; expression={Get-MailboxStatistics $_.samaccountname | select -ExpandProperty TotalItemSize}}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

**Edit 1:** The reason my question is not the same as [Powershell script with Get-Mailbox and Get-MailboxStatistics missing output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51031652/powershell-script-with-get-mailbox-and-get-mailboxstatistics-missing-output), as in the mentioned question the person was getting some results from their custom columns, just they were having issues with one row on one column, i don't even get results on the second or third rows.

**Edit 2:** I know i can create my own object, but i was trying to not to have to, this above code should be working (in a perfect world atleast). also the reason i'm not piping directly, i would've but i was trying to present my question with the least code possible to make it easier for the community to replicate it and to dissect it, the actual code i wanted to run is this

```
get-mailbox <username> | Get-MailboxStatistics | select displayname,TotalItemSize,@{name="Archive size";expression={Get-MailboxStatistics $_.samaccountname -archive | select -ExpandProperty TotalItemSize}}
```

My end goal was to get a table with a list of users with their mailbox size and their archive size.

Edit 3: never mind, i tried creating my own object and the same issue persisted. Provided my code used for the object.

```
 get-mailbox <username> | foreach {[pscustomobject]@{name = $_.name; "mailbox size" = Get-MailboxStatistics $_.samaccountname | select -expand TotalItemSize; "Archive size" = Get-MailboxStatistics $_.samaccountname -archive | select -expand TotalItemSize}}
```

Thanks again!

Comment: if you save the output of `Get-MailboxStatistics` to $Var, do you see a `TotalItemSize` property?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell script with Get-Mailbox and Get-MailboxStatistics missing output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51031652/powershell-script-with-get-mailbox-and-get-mailboxstatistics-missing-output)

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Yup, there is a TotalItemSize property.

Comment: @LotPings might be similar but i don't think it's the same, as 1. seems that over there they are able to get custom columns, just one value from row from one custom column was blank. by me the custom column doesn't ever return any value.

Comment: All examples I've seen so far either pipe `Get-Mailbox` to `Get-MailboxStatistics` or explicitly use the parameter name `-Identity`.

Comment: @Yeahish - i presume there was something in it, so that means you are getting the property with data from your call to that cmdlet. have you tried using `Foreach-Object` and building a `[PSCustomObject]` instead of using `Select-Object`?

Comment: @Yeahish - the question is not "why not do it this other way?" ... it's "does it work if you do it this other way?" [*grin*] it's fairly basic diagnostics ... do you have some non-obvious embedded character that is triggering the glitch? perhaps you will find out if you rewrite the code to use a different structure ...

Comment: @Lee_Dailey thanks, apparently there is an issue here, lets take my code apart.
If i run the get-mailboxstatistics it works fine, it only stops working if it's a custom column and it's the first or second column.

Comment: Seems like this is a known issue as you can see here https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/211b6d02-d807-4e04-b510-632eeb56c180/exchange-online-primary-and-archive-mailbox-sizes-in-one-command?forum=winserverpowershell and here https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/9bf45722-b459-4045-ab27-234eb7224f3d/how-to-find-the-mailbox-size-and-archive-mailbox-size-in-the-same-powershell-output?forum=winserverpowershell
So i guess i will have to give up.

Comment: @Yeahish - it _looks_ like something to do with how the identity is parsed. i don't have access to the AD/Exch/o365 stuff, so i am just reading posts & documentation. ///// at least you know how to work around it ... [*grin*]

Comment: Hmm, the original code works for me. Exchange 2013, Windows 2012, Powershell 3. Maybe upgrade your PS? Most likely PS v2 does not support piped expressions in selecting custom column.

Comment: @Vesper i tested the same code with get-process just replaced the piped reference with an actual username and it returned the correct results, if i try that with get-mailbox it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. Your code read like this:

```
get-mailbox <username> | Get-MailboxStatistics | select displayname,TotalItemSize,@{name="Archive size";expression={Get-MailboxStatistics $_.samaccountname -archive | select -ExpandProperty TotalItemSize}}
```

has an error. Your expression includes reference to `samaccountname` which is in `Get-Mailbox` output but not in `Get-MailboxStatistics` output, thus you're querying a null mailbox. To fix, query archive mailbox with a `displayName` attribute.

```
get-mailbox <username> | Get-MailboxStatistics | select displayname,TotalItemSize,@{name="Archive size";expression={Get-MailboxStatistics $_.displayname -archive | select -ExpandProperty TotalItemSize}}
```

Comment: Your code works. thanks!
Just to clarify, if you look at my first code you can see i didn't reference the samaccountname from get-mailboxstatistics as it's not in the pipeline, and it still doesn't work. why? (you are right about my second code)

Comment: Never mind, i see now you commented that the first code does works by you.

Comment: Why then if i explicitly reference a mailbox in the custom column expression doesn't it work? for example
`get-mailbox johndoe | select name,@{n="size";e={Get-MailboxStatistics "johndoe" | select TotalItemSize}}`

Comment: never mind, i just tested it locally on the actual server and it does work, so either the issue is with my powershell, or the issue is with how exchange communicates with remote powershell.
Thanks again for your help.